# Выписание строк в двумерном массиве, которые состоят из одинаковых цифр - Java

Tags: java

Всем привет,хочу выписывать в консоле строки в матрице которые являются анаграммами,
то есть, состоят  из одинаковых цифр, но не обязательно в одном и том же порядке,
и вот что я придумал, для начала я хочу отсортировать массив, что бы даже если строки содержат   одинаковые элементы, но в разном порядке то теперь у меня после сортировки строк, они будут   идентичны, и я теперь имею посортированую матрицу, и дальше мне нужно выписать только идентичные   строки (пример двумерного массива 3х3 `{{1,2,3},{2,1,3},{1,1,1}}`,
что я хочу вывести на экран в итоге - `{{1,2,3}, {2,1,3}}`), не знаю как это сделать, вот мой код, то что я имею на данный момент, буду рад за помощь:

```
public class Macierz {
    private int n;
    private int m;
    private int[][] macierz;
    private int max = 0;
    private int min = 0;

    public Macierz(int n, int m) {
        macierz = new int[n][m];
    }

    public int random (int max, int min) {
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
        max -= min;
        return (int) (Math.random() * max) + min;
    }

    public void wypelnij () {
        for (int i = 0; i < macierz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < macierz[i].length; j++) {
                macierz[i][j] = random(-1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void wypisz() {
        for (int i = 0; i < macierz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < macierz[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(macierz[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public void wypiszWierszy () {
        // сортировка строк матрицы
        int b;
        for (int i = 0; i < macierz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < macierz.length; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < macierz.length; k++) {
                    if (macierz[i][j] > macierz[i][k]) {
                        b = macierz[i][j];
                        macierz[i][j] = macierz[i][k];
                        macierz[i][k] = b;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант: реализовать метод, который сравнивает 2 одномерных массива на равенство. Затем пройтись по двумерному массиву как по одномерному состоящему из одномерных (строк в двумерном) по i = 0..n-1, j = i+1 ..n-1 , сравнивая массивы с индексами i и j этим самым методом. Если метод возвращает true, то выводим на консоль.
Про метод сравнения массивов, сначала оба сортируем Arrays.sort(...), а потом сравниваем Arrays.equals(...), тоже как вариант.